# Python Selenium Script ... Get Text using XPATH

Tags: python, selenium

Try to get the text from html page based on Xpath using python 2.7 selenium scripting ... Code Not Working is at the end of the script last 3 lines ... Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks

```
import os
import time
import webbrowser

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

#region Browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print("Browser: " + driver.name)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
#endregion

driver.get("http://xyz/...")

textName = "Max Size"

try:
    textElement = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span[16]')
    textContent = textElement.text
    print ("Text ... " + textContent)
...
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what it's not working? You get an error? You get nothing?

Comment: Share HTML in text. Try to use more consistent locator, like id, name, class. Use `WebDriverWait` to wait visibility of the element before getting text, this's the key.

Comment: Can you try ```driver.implicitly_wait(15)```  after  ```driver = webdriver.Firefox()``` ?